# Скачивание сформированного PERL-скриптом XLSX-файла пользователем в браузере

Tags: apache, perl

Есть perl-скрипт на apache-сервере, который подключается к БД Oracle, выгружает полученные данные в excel-файл: my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('/u03/report/result.xlsx'); Также данная табличка отображается и на самой странице в браузере. подскажите, как написать команду, чтобы появилась ссылка на самой странице с результатом, при нажатии на которую скачивался excel-файл пользователю. Я попробовал команду и ее вариации: print "download"; но получаю ошибку http 500, а в логах апача: (13) permission denied или (8) exec format error.

Comment: Ваш перловый скрипт должен подготовить сам документ, сохранить в известное ему место, доступное извне. А потом сформировать для пользователя обычный html документ, в который собственно вставить ссылку на этот документ.
А можно и просто сделать html документ с ссылкой на Ваш скрипт.

Comment: Да, мой скрипт так и делает! Выгружаются данные через SQL в переменные и далее ячейки excel заполняются этими данными. И сам готовый excel файл находится в папке на сервере, которую я указал. Тут все хорошо. Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы на страничке была ссылка для пользователя "Скачать", т е он ее нажимает и сохраняет этот файлик себе на компьютер. Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: Ваша папка должна  быть доступна для пользователей через веб. Это значит что ее надо сконфигурить в апаче:   Alias /download/ /datastore/byggeweb/download/
  <Directory /datastore/byggeweb/download/ >
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  EnableMMAP off
  EnableSendfile off
  </Directory>

Comment: Спасибо! Вы ответили на мой вопрос!

Comment: в httpd.conf так сделал:
Alias /xxx/ /u03/report/
<Directory /u03/report/ > 
Options None 
AllowOverride None 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
EnableMMAP off 
EnableSendfile off 
</Directory>

Comment: файл формируется сюда:my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('/u03/report/result.xlsx');

Comment: И ссылка на скачивание: print "<A href='/xxx/result.xlsx'>DOWNLOAD</A>";